# Why RDATA in EDNS(0) resource record has 1 octet?

Tags: dns

I want to understand why EDNS(0) resource records contains an extra octet? I read [RFC 6891](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6891) and [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035). It says nothing about case when RDLENGHT == 0 but RDATA == "\0".

To test this here python code

```py
import binascii
import socket


def send_udp_message(message, address, port):
    """send_udp_message sends a message to UDP server

    message should be a hexadecimal encoded string
    """
    message = message.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
    server_address = (address, port)

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        sock.sendto(binascii.unhexlify(message), server_address)
        data, _ = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    finally:
        sock.close()
    return binascii.hexlify(data).decode("utf-8")


def format_hex(hex):
    """format_hex returns a pretty version of a hex string"""
    octets = [hex[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(hex), 2)]
    pairs = [" ".join(octets[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(octets), 2)]
    return "\n".join(pairs)


message = "AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 " \
"07 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01 "

# EDNS(0) resource record
message += "00 00 " # NAME
message += "29 00 " # TYPE
message += "FF 00 00 80 " # TTL
message += "00 00 " # RDLENGTH
# message += "00" # RDATA

response = send_udp_message(message, "8.8.8.8", 53)
print(format_hex(response))
```

Dns query returns here error. But if uncomment RDATA line it returns success.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason to want to generate DNS packets by hand instead of using a library to do it for now, like `dnspython`? You can use it to learn too, as it can show the wire format of any packet you generate with the high level API.

Comment: I write own implementation and learning protocol. Here python only for test purposes. I use C++ for my lib.

Comment: You still can use libraries to see how they generate packets and compare with your own results.

Comment: Anyway how this help me with my question? Or you want to say that RFC lies?

Comment: For what it's worth, WireShark has a very good DNS decoder with a hex view so you can compare your interpretation with its to see where things differ. It can also explode view your own packets to show if there's any mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

You misread section §6.1.2 of RFC 6891, so the RFCs are not "lies".

It says:

```
       +------------+--------------+------------------------------+
       | Field Name | Field Type   | Description                  |
       +------------+--------------+------------------------------+
       | NAME       | domain name  | MUST be 0 (root domain)      |
       | TYPE       | u_int16_t    | OPT (41)                     |
       | CLASS      | u_int16_t    | requestor's UDP payload size |
       | TTL        | u_int32_t    | extended RCODE and flags     |
       | RDLEN      | u_int16_t    | length of all RDATA          |
       | RDATA      | octet stream | {attribute,value} pairs      |
       +------------+--------------+------------------------------+
```

so 6 pieces of information while your code has only 5 pieces:

```
# EDNS(0) resource record
message += "00 00 " # NAME
message += "29 00 " # TYPE
message += "FF 00 00 80 " # TTL
message += "00 00 " # RDLENGTH
# message += "00" # RDATA
```

You are missing the CLASS between TYPE and TTL, hence things are not interpreted the way you think they are.
You are also misreading how the bytes work for the name.
It is not:

```
00 00       NAME
29 00       TYPE
FF 00 00 80 TTL
00 00       RDLENGTH
```

but really:

```
00          NAME (root domain per EDNS(0) specification, which is a sole zero)
00 29       TYPE (41, per specification)
00 FF       CLASS (255, considered as payload)
00 00 80 00 TTL, read as 00 = EXTENDED-CODE, 00 = VERSION (mandatory), 80 = DO set plus everything else 0 as the final 00 byte, per specification
00          RDLENGTH
```

and the final item RDLENGTH is then not properly formatted per the RFC 1035 specification as it is 2 bytes (16 bits).
Once you comment your last line, RDLENGTH becomes 00 00 and then is valid.
And there is indeed no RDATA part in your message.

What you believe being a 00 value in RDATA is in fact the last byte of RDLENGTH but you did not parse the stream correctly.

Had you used `dnspython` as advised to you, you would have seen the problem immediately with the proper mapping of fields:

```
In [1]: import dns

In [2]: import dns.message

In [10]: stream = 'AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 07 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 29 00 FF 00 00 80 00 00 00'

In [11]: data=''.join(chr(int(x, base=16)) for x in stream.split(' '))

In [12]: m = dns.message.from_wire(data)

In [13]: print m
id 43690
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags RD
edns 0
eflags DO
payload 255
;QUESTION
example.com. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

Had you wanted to do that you could have simulated the expected bytes stream that way:

```
(starting from your message)

In [31]: m = dns.message.from_wire(data)

In [32]: print m
id 43690
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags RD
edns 0
eflags DO
payload 255
;QUESTION
example.com. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL

(creating a new one to look like yours)

In [39]: mm = dns.message.make_query('example.com.', 'A', use_edns=0, payload=255, want_dnssec=True)

In [40]: mm.id=43690

In [41]: print mm
id 43690
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags RD
edns 0
eflags DO
payload 255
;QUESTION
example.com. IN A
;ANSWER
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL


(now looking at its wire representation)

In [46]: print ' '.join(hex(ord(d)) for d in mm.to_wire())
0xaa 0xaa 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x7 0x65 0x78 0x61 0x6d 0x70 0x6c 0x65 0x3 0x63 0x6f 0x6d 0x0 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x1 0x0 0x0 0x29 0x0 0xff 0x0 0x0 0x80 0x0 0x0 0x0
```

Comparing with your bytestream:

```
dnspython: AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 07 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 29 00 FF 00 00 80 00 00 00

you:       AA AA 01 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 01 07 65 78 61 6d 70 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 29 00 FF 00 00 80 00 00
```

Note the missing final `00` being in your commented line.

This shows that existing good libraries, as `dnspython` is, really help sometimes better understanding RFCs or other specifications. And in the world of DNS there are many RFCs, sometimes conflicting between each other, with ambiguous parts, etc. So using existing libraries for tests and/or studying their source code really helps, if you want this advice.